# Difference between add() and offer() methods of Queue interface

Tags: java, queue, fifo

I was going though FIFO implementation in Java and came across this java.util.Queue interface. Dequeue implements it which in turn is implemented by Linked List.

I wrote the following code

```
public class FIFOTest {

    public static void main(String args[]){

        Queue<String> myQueue = new LinkedList<String>();
        myQueue.add("US");
        myQueue.offer("Canada");

        for(String element : myQueue){
            System.out.println("Element : " + element);
        }
    }

}
```

Both seem to do the same thing. Add data to the head of the queue. What is the difference between these two methods? Any special cases in which either would be more beneficial than other?

Comment: It's described in the very first paragraph of [`Queue` javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`LinkedList#offer(E)` is implemented as

```
public boolean offer(E e) {
    return add(e);
}
```

In this case, they are the same thing. They are just needed to satisfy the interfaces. `LinkedList` implements `Deque` and `List`. The `LinkedList#add(E)` method will not throw an `Exception` as it will always take more elements, but in another `Queue` implementation that has limited capacity or takes only certain kinds of elements, `add(E)` might throw an exception while `offer(E)` will simply return `false`.

Comment: I guess same goes for poll() and remove()?

Comment: @Aniket Not exactly. `poll` will return `null` if there are no elements. `remove()` will throw a `NoSuchElementException`.

Comment: It's the same idea though: `offer()` and `poll()` return special values on failure, while `add()` and `remove()` throw exceptions.

Answer (score 3):

According to [the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html) the main difference is that when the operation fails, one (`add`) throws an exception and the other (`offer`) returns a special value (`false`):

> Each of these methods exists in two forms: one throws an exception if the operation fails, the other returns a special value (either null or false, depending on the operation). The latter form of the insert operation is designed specifically for use with capacity-restricted Queue implementations; in most implementations, insert operations cannot fail.

Answer (score 3):

> What is the difference between these two methods?

- **Queue.add** -  throws an exception if the operation fails,
- **Queue.offer**-  returns a special value (either `null` or `false`, depending on the operation).

> Any special cases in which either would be more beneficial than other?

According to docs, The **Queue.offer** form of the insert operation is designed specifically for
use with capacity-restricted Queue implementations; in most
implementations, insert operations cannot fail.

For details, read this [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html).

Answer (score 2):

- `add()` comes from `Collection` Interface.
- `offer()` comes from `Queue` Interface.

The Documentation of `offer()` method of Queue says

```
  Inserts the specified element into this queue if it is possible to do
  so immediately without violating capacity restrictions.
  When using a capacity-restricted queue, this method is generally
  preferable to {@link #add}, which can fail to insert an element only
  by throwing an exception.
```

The Documentation of `add()` method of Queue says

```
 Inserts the specified element into this queue if it is possible to do so
 immediately without violating capacity restrictions, returning
 <tt>true</tt> upon success and throwing an <tt>IllegalStateException</tt>
 if no space is currently available.
```